# Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'UserModel' doesn't allow null

Tags: flutter, dart

[solve error please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXJRy.jpg)

lib/features/personalization/models/user_model.dart:63:11: Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'UserModel' doesn't allow null.

- 'UserModel' is from 'package:wheelsonrent/features/personalization/models/user_model.dart' ('lib/features/personalization/models/user_model.dart').
  factory UserModel.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> document){Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'UserModel' doesn't allow null.

Answer (score 0):

If `document.data()` is null, what should `UserModel.fromSnapshot` return?

- If null, change your declaration to

  ```dart
  static UserModel? fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> document) {
    if (document.data() != null) {
      return UserModel(/*...*/);
    }
    return null;
  }
  ```
- If some default data, change your declaration to

  ```dart
  factory UserModel.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> document) {
    if (document.data() != null) {
      return UserModel(/*...*/);
    }
    return UserModel(/*...*/);
  }
  ```

If you're sure `document.data()` can't ever be null, change your declaration to

```dart
factory UserModel.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> document) {
  final data = document.data()!;
  return UserModel(/*...*/);
}
```